# Moving wordpress multi to different domain and vhost - cannot log in and menu problems

Tags: multisite, domain, virtual-hosts

I am trying to move a wordpress multi install to a different vhost on the same server and a different domain. Currently we are testing the process by copying everything to a new vhost, with a new database to try out the process before we move the production sites.

I can visit the new domain and see the sites we moved. The internal links have updated to use the new domain. Unfortunately the menu links all point to the old domain and I cannot find any reference to that domain in the database. I also cannot log into wordpress. I go to http://newdomain/wp-login.php and log in with the admin user. I am redirected to and logged into the dashboard at olddomain.com.

Procedure:

1. Do a mysql dump of current site
2. Create new database, dbuser
3. import mysql dump into new database
4. copy entire vhost with wordpress install over to new virtual host
5. update wp-config with new database name, dbuser, password, and siteurl
6. searched through all files in vhost (theme files, everything) for the old domain and replaced with new domain
7. create an apache entry for the site
8. updated fields in wp_(x)_posts, wp_site, wp_blogs, wp_sitemeta
9. when updating the fields in the database above still did not resolve the issue

   - Used the search and replace tool (http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) recommended by the codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite)
   - searched a dump of the entire database and still failed to find a reference to the old url

I tried following the documentation I found and none of these seemed to resolve my issues:
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite
- https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
- http://tech.ipstenu.org/2012/moving-wordpress-multisite/

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Glad to see somebody using our search replace tool

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the search replace on ALL wordpress tables. You will have missed the entries in the options table as well as many other locations such as post meta, etc

Comment: Tom Nowell:
We did do the search/replace on all tables. At first we just manually did the tables named in the original post (as per http://tech.ipstenu.org/2012/moving-wordpress-multisite/), but later we tried your utility to replace in all tables. Still doesn't work.

Comment: did you use the tool on the original data or the hand modified data?

Comment: We used the tool on the original data.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems.
Did you look in your wp-config file for your multisite declaration infos?

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.domain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/blog/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

It's often missed.
You may also have some links in js, php files and plugins (do you use a special plugin for your menu)?
Have you checked your .htaccess file?

In your DB did you changed Site AND Home options in wp_options table?
If your WordPress site is completely broken, then you can add the following values to wp-config.php, which should have the same effect:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://your_server/your_blog_url');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://your_server/your_wordpress_url');
```

And last if you did a fresh wordpress install, is it the same WP versions? Be carefull to have the same users, passwords etc It seems that the nombre and order of users has to match the database. (You can delete the transcient in your DB which are used like a query cache.
At the end delete the cookies refering to your site in your browser.
Hope it helped